# Can we continue the execution of the protractor script even if a error like no such element is detected

Tags: protractor

I am using Protractor 5.2.2.I am running a protractor script in a loop.Is there any possibility to execute protractor script without lose its control(shutdown abnormally)even if a error like no such element is detected.While i am running the script in a loop,sometimes error occurs and the browser shutdown quickly.So I need to continue the loop execution even an element is not fount in between the loop execution.Is it possible?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jasmine framework, you can use `jasmine --stop-on-failure=false` in `spec/support/jasmine.json`